# StoreKit.framework deleted from Library directory

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any change to get StoreKit.framework from iOS SDK 8.3 if I accidentally deleted it (without downloading Xcode again)?

It was linked to one of my projects, at some point I needed to delete it but instead of pressing "Remove reference", I pressed "Move to trash" and also "Emptied trash" after that...so now I'm unable to get it back.

Thanks,
Alin

Comment: I found this Project on GitHub but it doesn't work: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Any other sites that hosts apple framework would already be taken down for copyright issues (except maybe open source frameworks). You need to reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @ALN sorry there couldn't be a better way.

Comment: Ok. I just reinstalled Xcode and now it works fine. Thanks for your time!